# How to create a div grid with equal spacing in a flexible layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to creat a layout like this:

[image]

My question is specifically centered around the five boxes. I struggle with the CSS to get it to work. Have you guys got a simple setup for such a layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have fixed width, so here is an example. Widths are not exact for your width, but you can esily set values you need. Main thing here is `float:left` in small_bottom class which makes div to be shown in one row. `overflow:hidden` in bottom class makes that div wrap around floating divs (without that it will be shown like there is nothing inside). If you want this depend on browser window width - try using percents in width for small_bottom.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="small_bottom"></div>
        <div class="small_bottom"></div>
        <div class="small_bottom"></div>
        <div class="small_bottom"></div>
        <div class="small_bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div{border:solid 1px;}
.main{width:350px; border:solid 1px;}
.top{ height:40px;margin:5px;}
.small_bottom{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin:5px;
}
.bottom{margin:5px; overflow:hidden;}

​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/S4STr/2/) is an example how it looks